# Ecw not supported with qgis-mapserv-fcgi but supported in QGIS Desktop

Tags: qgis, qgis-server, ecw

I have problem with qgis-mapserver version 2 and ECW.

Qgis Desktop works well with ECW (gdal support for ecw with the library ERDAS_ECWJP2_SDK-5.0) but not qgis-mapserver (not supported file in Apache error logs).

qgis-server must use the same gdal librarie that qgis desktop (QGIS desktop and server are all 2 installed on my computer (ubuntu 12.10). This is what I do not understand.

Note:

> I just watched the license to use the ERDAS_ECWJP2_SDK-5.0, including
>   this paragraph: 1.9. "Server Application" means clustering software
>   products That You Develop or maintain maintenance and are able of
>   running on a Server To Provide an image decoding or processing
>   capability. This License Agreement Does not Authorize You to use the
>   SDK to create Server Applications.
>
> With this SDK for a "free" installation, or it is installed with a
>   "Desktop Read-Only" license or with a license "Server Read-Only End
>   User" but not the 2.
>
> Next time, I would read longer uses licenses, something I rarely do.